# Redirect from domain to other domain subpage with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

How can I, via an .htaccess file, redirect `somepage.com` to `somepage.dk/en`

I know I can use the Rewrite module and do something like (not tested):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^somedomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://somedomain.dk/en [R=301,L]
```

But all pages on `somepage.com` should redirect to `somepage.dk/en`

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty close, you have rewrite condition reversed and you need to use captured match in target URI:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^somedomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://somedomain.dk/en/$1 [R=301,L]
```